# Invoke HTML5 inputs by dragging

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML5 inputs to select a date.

I simply want to open that input if the users clicks on a specific image but I can't force the mobile browsers to open their datepickers.

Here is the element:

```
<input type="date" class="dateInput" name="day" id="day">
```

Simple question: 
How to open in with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 datepickers open when  the users focuses a form element. If you click/touch an image this is not the same as getting the focus.

But you could probably emulate this behavior by firing the focus-event on  the image-click:

```
jQuery( '#date-input-image-1' ).click( function() {
    jQuery( '#date-input-1' ).focus();
} )
```

Comment: I already tried that. It is selecting the element but nothing else happens.